# asp.net app connects to localDB instead of my remote DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have what strongly looks like a connection string issue into my ASP.NET MVC project (VS2013).

I wanted to set the model via Entity Framework from my existing SQLServer database.
I added an ADO.NET entity data model into my model directory.
I followed the steps and EF apparently correctly created the 6 model classes from my 6 DB tables. This at least worked fine.
Now, when I run the project, the application connects to the LocalDB v11.0 instead of the DB it used to create the entities.

I suppose it s all about web.config but I am still too noob to get it sorted.
web.config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=&quot;|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Impro MVC-20160114025340.mdf&quot;;Initial Catalog=&quot;aspnet-Impro MVC-20160114025340&quot;;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /><add name="ImproDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DBImpro.csdl|res://*/Models.DBImpro.ssdl|res://*/Models.DBImpro.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DBNAME.SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.com;initial catalog=ImproDB;persist security info=True;user id=MYLOGIN;password=PASS;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /><add name="ImproDBEntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DBImpro.csdl|res://*/Models.DBImpro.ssdl|res://*/Models.DBImpro.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DBNAME.SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.com;initial catalog=DBNAME;persist security info=True;user id=MYLOGIN;password=MYPASS;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

I replaced this with :

```
   <connectionStrings>
 <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=DBNAME.SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.com;packet size=4096;user id=MYLOGIN;pwd=PASS;data source=DBNAME.SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=ImproDB" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

But it still connects to the localDB. Shouldn t it connect to the DB I set after this change????

I can also see below this part relative to the DB:

```
 <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```

I suppose this must be what I need to update. If I comment this part, the application cannot start:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server....

Any clue how to get this solved?

Thx in advance.

EDIT:
as I used Database first in EF, here's the code of the BDDContext

```
 public partial class ImproDBEntities1 : DbContext
    {
        public ImproDBEntities1()
            : base("name=ImproDBEntities1")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Categories_Impro> Categories_Impro { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Cours_Impro> Cours_Impro { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Ex_Impro> Ex_Impro { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Spectacle_Impro> Spectacle_Impro { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Categories_Du_Spectacle> Categories_Du_Spectacle { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Ex_du_Cours> Ex_du_Cours { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You need to simply change the web config section for defaultConnectionFactory.

Comment: `parameter value="v11.0"` is the culprit causing your problems.  I have explained all that in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OPTION 1** : Just change the web config setting of `defaultConnectionFactory` to what is given below and you should be all set. The latest EF will automatically use this setting to determine which database to connect to. The disadvantage of this approach is that your connections would be scattered in multiple sections in your web config file.

```
<entityFramework> 
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"> 
    <parameters> 
      <parameter value="Data Source=DBNAME.SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.com;packet size=4096;user id=MYLOGIN;pwd=PASS;data source=DBNAME.SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=ImproDB;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" /> 
    </parameters> 
  </defaultConnectionFactory> 
</entityFramework>
```

**OPTION 2** : Another option for you would be to specify in the connection strings section another connection string that looks like below. Replace the  parts that begin with `BloggingModel`  with model name of your EF model. *This would be better than the first approach mentioned above, since your connection strings would all be within the same section in web config file.* Replace the `ConnectionStringName` in below configuration with any name you want to use.

```
  <add name="ConnectionStringName"  
        connectionString="metadata=res://*/BloggingModel.csdl| 
                                                       res://*/BloggingModel.ssdl| 
                                                       res://*/BloggingModel.msl; 
                                           provider=System.Data.SqlClient 
                                           provider connection string= 
                                               &quot;Data Source=DBNAME.SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.com;packet size=4096;user id=MYLOGIN;pwd=PASS;data source=DBNAME.SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=ImproDB;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Thx for your answer.
Option 1: I get error:
CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'
Makes no sense to me as the DB contains all the needed tables so VS should not attemt to create any DB or tables....

Comment: Make sure that the database `ImproDB` already exists in your remote database? Obviously it seems it does not exis from your error message.

Comment: Well, it does. Remember I used this very DB to generate the model from the DB. And VS could find it correctly at this time since he correctly generated the Model classes.

Comment: So you are not using code-first. Can you post your code for the DatbaseContext class you are using?

Comment: If you are using Model-First approach then EF will try to recreate everything in remote database on every publish of your model for which you will need enhanced permissions in remote database, so I suggest you switch to Database-First approach.

Comment: Where is the connection string `name=ImproDBEntities1`?

Comment: Also please state clearly what approach you are using-  Database First or Model First or Code First? This matters a lot.

Comment: Well I firstly set EF to generate the model from the remote DB.
I have no experience with it, now that Model clsses are correctly generated, I only want it to connect to the DB when I start the application.
I thought the default generated app.config would just do that...

Comment: So you are using Database First. In that case where is the connection string `name=ImproDBEntities1`?

Comment: Are you changing the model in Visual Studio?

Comment: I don't have any. That must be the source of the mess. Thx for this first improvement :)
I only had in my webconfig a name="DefaultConnection" that VS generated. I thought it was the only one that needed to be setupped.

So I tried to add:
 <add name="ImproDBEntities1" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" connectionString="..."/>
I still get the  Option 1: I get error: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'  error.

Does it matter if I set providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"  or providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  ? I do not know the difference.

Comment: Yes, use exactly as its in OPTION 2.

Comment: Did you create  EF model or some other developer? If you created it, then did you run the EF Wizard to create the model and please tell me which of the four options you selected in the wizard.

Comment: I am 100% sure that you did not run the EF Wizard correctly and that is the cause of all your problems, else it would have created the connection string for you automatically. My only recommendation in that case is to create a new EF project and make sure you select the first option in Ef Wizard which creates the model from existing database and specify the connection string when the Wizard runs. ELSE you can spend many days trying to solve this problem.

Comment: Into a brand new ASP.NET project, I included an ADO.NET entity data model and selected database first.
Same procedure as this guy : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-cV_fSNMqw (2min17).

Comment: I am 100% sure you did not follow that guy else why was your connection string not created? EF automatically creates the connection string and you are supposed to specify the connection string in the Wizard itself. Start from a new project and this time  PLEASE specify what connection string you want to use.

Comment: OK, I ll just retry from scratch and LYK, thx for the suggestion Sunil.

Comment: Remember if you are using Database First, the connection string under OPTION 2 in my answer should be there in the web config after you run the Wizard. If its not there then there is a problem  and you should re-start.

Comment: This was definitely the wisest option ever :)
I started all again from scratch and it worked at first try. 
This time, the correct connection string had been correctly added into web.config.
Thanks a ton for your patience in assisting me, I really appreciated your help Sunil.
Have an excellent week end.

Comment: You are welcome A D. Glad that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

One of the overloads for the `DbContext` class constructor takes the name of the connection string, in your case `DefaultConnection`. You can pass this as a string when you create a new instance of your `DbContext` class.

Personally I like to create a default constructor in my own `DbContext` class that then calls the `DbContext` constructor with the correct named connection string.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
   public MyDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection"){}
}
```

Also make sure you define your connection string in the `web.config` or `app.config` of the executing application and not in the library or some other project even if that is the project where you define your `DbContext` class.

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide the `connectionString` outside of `<entityFramework>` tags:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <!-- whatever -->
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```